# Laying out footer grid with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a few issues achieving the type of grid I need at the moment. It's a footer so I want it to be 12 columns long, two stacked on top of each other. Each will contain its own content. But at the "end" of this grid I want a big logo image. Here's an example.

[image]

As you can see there are 3 columns. I'd like there to be 4, but the 4th needs to be a height of 100%, not two stacked like the rest. Here is what I have so far.

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">1</div>

      <div class="col-md-3">2</div>

      <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">1</div>

      <div class="col-md-3">2</div>

      <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: add max-width:100% for image

Comment: @LaljiTadhani Where do I add the 4th col-md though? I've tried adding max-width:100% when I added the 4th col to the first row, but it pushed the entire bottom row down. I don't want the image pushing the bottom image down.

Comment: add your code fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/2YYcSDo2NY)**

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">Img</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam hoping this is what you are looking for:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this for `md` screen..

**HTML**

```css
.first-row {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.second-row {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.image-column {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row first-row">
          <div class="col-md-4">1</div>

          <div class="col-md-4">2</div>

          <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
        </div>


        <div class="row second-row">
          <div class="col-md-4">1</div>

          <div class="col-md-4">2</div>

          <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 image-column">
        <img src="..." , alt="..." />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is what you want...

```
<footer>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"><img src="" class="img-responsive"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kind of. This still pushes the second row down though. I want there to be the top row (1,2,3) and a bottom row right below it (another 1,2,3). I can't have the bottom row be pushed down from the image.